# Error trying to apply algorithms to data set in Python, using SKlearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

Trying to run my data set through PCA using SKlearn for a machin learning assingment. Not sure what i'm doing wrong?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFqyE.jpg

edit:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import skimage.feature
trnImages = np.load('trnImage.npy')
trnidx = 20

plt.imshow(trnImages[:,:,:,trnidx])

def computeFeatures(image):
```

Comment: Could you post here the code that results in an error, and what that error is?

Comment: Thanks for replying to the post, added code

Comment: Cool. What problem are you encountering? Is there an error message?

Comment: what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo. Change

```
pca = PCA(n_componetns = 2)
```

to

```
pca = PCA(n_components = 2)
```

Also make sure that the data you are running PCA on is numeric, because PCA solves an optimization problem that requires numeric features. So if you have an image, make sure you factorize/vectorize the image.